# Невозможно создать подключение Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper, connection

При попытке создания нового подключения выдаёт ошибку "The network adapter could not establish the connection". Перепробовал советы из гугла, часть не работает просто (добавление разных настроек в sqldeveloper.conf), часть не могу применить, так как нет файлов listener.ora и tnsnames.ora, в службах нет никаких запущенных и вообще любых служб Oracle. Сам Oracle SQL Developer скачан с официального сайта Oracle, версия "19.2.1.247.2212 - September 12, 2019" для Windows 64-bit. Сама программа нужна для выполнения лабораторной работы в университете, работаю с ней первый раз и вообще не разбираюсь.
По опыту с работой с другими базами данных, предполагаю, что возможно нужно как-то инициализировать или создать непосредственно базу данных, но не нашёл как там это сделать. По заданию нужно базу создать на основе скрипта модели из SQL Developer Data Modeler.

Comment: А здесь искать не пробовали? [Поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+Network+adapter+could+not+establish+the+connection).

Comment: Пока как понял, вы пытаетесь подключится к БД, которой ещё нет? Если это не так, то где устновлена БД?  _По заданию нужно базу создать на основе скрипта модели из SQL Developer Data Modeler_, уточните детали задания с тем, кто выдадл вам задание. С SQL Developer Data Modeler создаётся логическая модель БД, но этот инструмент не устанавливает БД.

Comment: @0xdb Да, вы правильно поняли, спасибо большое за ответ. Вот у меня есть скрипт и есть логическая модель. Соответственно, чтобы создать подключение нужно сначала создать пустую базу данных в SQL Developer, правильно?

Comment: _нужно сначала создать пустую базу данных в SQL Developer, правильно?_, нет, не правильно. SQL Developer не создаёт БД. Вам надо скачать установщик с оф.сайта, установить ПО, создать постую БД с ODBC, создать пользователя БД, подключится  с каким либо клиентом к БД, и выполнять скрипты, которые созданы с  SQL Developer Data Modeler. Вот так правильно.

Comment: @0xdb спасибо вам большое, а какой софт нужен для создания базы данных?

Comment: [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html).  Там  есть инструменты для создания базы данных, они будут предложены во время установки.